# Convert a formula to array formuar

Tags: google-sheets

I am struggling converting the below formula to a array format is it posible?

```
=Iferror(IF(INDEX('Prep List'!$C$3:$C,MATCH(E6,'Prep List'!$E$3:$E,),1)=1,"✔️",""),"")
```

Below is the closest i got

```
=Iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDEX('Prep List'!C2:C,MATCH(E6;6,'Prep List'!E2:E,),1)=TRUE,"✔️",""),""))
```

the formlaur works when i copy it down the row but was looking for a more elegant option

any help would be amazing

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet, as well as the outcome you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(E6:E), IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(E6:E, {'Prep List'!$E$3:$E, 'Prep List'!$C$3:$C},2, 0)+0=1,"✔️",)),))
```

or, using index() and match()

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(E6:E), IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Prep List'!$C$3:$C, match(E6:E, 'Prep List'!$E$3:$E, 0))+0=1,"✔️",)),))
```

Comment: Thanks @ JPV for your help the Vlookup worked great.

Couldn't get the index and match to work but hey i am happy